How to delete or edit a mongodb document without an _id?
Somehow, there is a document without an _id in my database. It can be pulled, but cannot be saved or deleted.
The document looks something like the following:
{
  name: 'John Smith',
  key: 'abc123',
  data: [
    'Lorem ipsum',
    'dolor sic amet'
  ]
}


And my Schema looks like the following:
personSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    data: { type: Array },
    key: String
})

Note, the key field is completely detached from the id and is used internally, and all other documents in the collection have an _id field.
The following code produces the error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: No _id found on document!:
personSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    data: { type: Array },
    key: String
});
Person = mongoose.model('entries', personSchema);
let entries = await Person.find({key: "abc123"});
let toDelete;
entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(!entry._id){
        toDelete = entry;
    }
});
toDelete.delete();


1. A document in a collection not having an _id is impossible. Raise a P1 ticket if you somehow created it. 2. Wrt "If I try to delete it with entry.delete()" - show your code for how you retrieved entry in the first place. Show what you have tried so far (code) in a Minimal, Reproducible Example. 3. For MongooseError: No _id found on document! you are probably using the wrong schema or haven't defined it correctly. Do your models use id instead of _id?

4. "It can be pulled, but cannot be saved or deleted." As mentioned above, show your code for how you're pulling it and how you're trying to edit/delete it. Also show your Schema.

I'm not sure how to make this reproducible when I don't know how the entry was created in the first place. And as for it being impossible, obviously it isn't because it happened somehow.

May be you disabled _id through mongoose? What @aneroid saying is making sense since all documents in MongoDB must be associated with _id. The only possibility that I can think of is that your schema is a sub-document. A sub-document can have no _id in MongoDB

Try fetching that document with mongosh or compass to see what it actually looks like in the database.

Your .delete() is asynchronous but you aren't handling it as asynchronous. Use .deleteOne() instead.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    data: { type: Array },
    key: String
});

const Person = mongoose.model('entries', personSchema);

async function deleteEntry() {
    try {
        let entries = await Person.find({ key: "abc123" });
        let toDelete;

        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (!entry._id) {
                toDelete = entry;
            }
        });

        if (toDelete) {
            await toDelete.deleteOne();
        } else {
            console.log("No document found without an _id or all documents have an _id.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    }
}

deleteEntry();

Side note: It is possible to create documents without an _id. But I don't think that's what's going on in your situation.
const childSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
}, { _id: false });

const parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childSchema],
  familyName: String
});

const ParentModel = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);

The parent document will have an _id, but the child document will not.

This worked as mentioned in my own answer. And yeah, I somehow managed to get a parent schema with no _id. Still not sure how that happened, though I think it may have come from duplicating data.

Ok, so I still have no idea how the document in question was created, but I was able to delete it simply with the following:
personSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    data: { type: Array },
    key: String
});
Person = mongoose.model('entries', personSchema);
await Person.deleteOne({key: "abc123"});

And then verifying that the correct entry was deleted.
